# Can't refer code listings

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, code

```
 \lstinputlisting[
   numbers=left,
   breaklines=true,
   caption={Kalukasjon av esker},
   label={list:LuaKalk},
   language={[5.0]Lua} ,
   firstline=139, 
   lastline=168]
   {code/Main.lua}


 \ref{LuaKalk}
```

Can't seem to be able to refer this listing, figures and cite works fine.
Suggestions? Writing on my bachelor's paper over at OverLeaf

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, you are much much more likely to get fast help if you provide a full but minimal example showing your problem. Then others can just copy this an start debugging immediately. Here we need to guess 3/4 of the document. BTW: what does this code has to do with `tcpinputlisting`, this seems to be just `listings`

Comment: Seems to me that you need to use `\ref{list:LuaKalk}`.

Comment: @daleif i did consider posting the whole main.tex but tought it would contain mostly Irreverent information.

Comment: Not the whole doc, a minimal one, only using what ever is relevant to show this problem. Preparing such a minimal document (basically you make a copy somewhere else, and start removing stuff), is a vital tool in learning to debug LaTeX. People have a tendency to steer away from examples that are 1000s of lines long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a normal user error, the label is `list:LuaKalk` but you refer to `\ref{LuaKalk}` which should have been `\ref{list:LuaKalk}`

Comment: Worked, i tried this earlier but stopped before acutally refreshing the preview, as the auto-completion-suggestion bar didn't show this as an option. Thanks!

Comment: @MelvinLangvik The auto completion probably looks for explicit `\label{key}`, but here this is hidden in the belly of `listings`